# What does purple shading with diagonal lines mean in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I am somewhat familiar with using Chromium Developer tools to inspect elements, and the color coded highlighting to show margin as orange, padding as green, and blue is the element itself. I was working on getting to know a React-based codebase unfamiliar to me, and when I hovered over a component I saw a purple box with top-left to bottom-right diagonal lines, and wasn't sure what this meant. What I did notice is that these elements with this purple shading tend to be contained within Flexboxes, and my best guess is that it has to do with the flex spacing, but I wanted to ask around to see if anyone knows what this really means. Here's an example:

[Purple Box with diagonal lines in developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCdI6.png)